# Why am I getting "File to import not found or unreadable"?

Tags: vue.js, sass, sass-loader

I have a simple vuejs app where I'm trying to import a scss file to `App.vue` (The main entry ponit of the app) with:

```
<style lang="scss">
    @import '~/css/app.scss';
</style>
```

(I also tried `@import 'app.scss';` - I can see `site.css` in the intellisense here, but not `app.scss` (they're in the same folder)).

But I'm getting this error:

> @import '~/css/app.scss';
>
> ^
>
> File to import not found or unreadable: ~/css/app.scss.

Other answers to this question only mention adding `includePath` to my `sass-loader` configuration and passing in `node_modeles`, but that doesn't seem to work. I also passed in the path to `app.scss` but with no luck.

**webpack.config.js**

```
...

module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.vue$/, loader: 'vue-loader' },
        { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', query: { presets: ['es2015'] } },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader'] },                
        { test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url-loader' },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                "vue-style-loader",
                "css-loader",
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                    options: {
                        includePaths: ["./node_modules", "./Web/wwwroot/css"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        // ESLint rules
        {
            test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'eslint-loader',
            enforce: 'pre',
            include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "App")],
            options: {
                eslintPath: path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/eslint'),
                fix: true,
                formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
                emitError: false,
                emitWarning: false,
                failOnError: true,
                failOnWarning: false
            }
        }
    ]
},

...
```

Comment: What's the absolute path of you CSS file?  `~` is a reference to 'node_modules', is that what you're intending here?

Comment: @jimikara Entire path is `C:\Users\Bassie\source\repos\Project101\Web\wwwroot\css\app.scss` I'm not trying to reference `node_modules`, I just want to import my file.

Comment: You have `~/` at the beginning of the import path which usually in Webpack is an alias for `/node_modules` (unless you've configured your own aliases), so the path you're trying to import from is equivalent to `node_modules/css/app.scss`

Comment: @jimikara As I mentioned in the question I already tried without the `~` but with the same result